# Class action left handed lawsuit?

Tags: discrimination, education, class-action

Left or right hand dominance is congenital. Suppose a child incurred a disorder such as dyslexia from being taught to use the non-dominant hand (as many have been due to the lack of left handed equipment, or teacher preference for conformity). Who would be responsible for the malpractice?

The comments in [this article](https://www.anythinglefthanded.co.uk/being-lh/children/changing-left-to-right.html) suggest many children were negatively affected from this. Do any of them have a legal case?

(Notice there are a few left handed desks on the far left in [this picture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiFn7Pyw8LjAhUGQq0KHTBtC6YQjhx6BAgBEAM&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.change.org%2Fp%2Fnational-school-national-school-boards-association-state-board-of-education-promote-necessary-left-handed-desks-in-every-college-classroom&psig=AOvVaw0ggU3inKChtOwLIoNKYYiK&ust=1563678814780789).  Ideally I think they should not isolate the left-handed people on the edge of the classroom.)

Comment: Forced righthandedness will cause damage to the ganglia in the brain (wiring).This leads to stuttering,speech & language issues.The damage can be seen with a MRI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can children that are force to write with the wrong hand that has developed a major disorder bring suit for malpractice?

That would be an unfounded and futile claim. The plaintiff would have a very hard time proving that his alleged disorder originated from being forced to write with the wrong hand.

Even *if* an expert witness lent himself to support plaintiff's claim, it will always be easier for the defendant to outweigh that testimony by presenting abundant evidence that is more credible. And that is a big *if* because plaintiff's expert witness has so much to lose in terms of credentials & qualifications by endorsing such a bizarre diagnosis.

Comment: Its not so bizzare. https://www.anythinglefthanded.co.uk/being-lh/children/changing-left-to-right.html Obviously that page is not in itself proof, but it does suggest that the claim should not be dismissed.

Comment: @PaulJohnson I am by no means knowledgeable in neurology, but a website with generic statements and a link about a [film](https://www.anythinglefthanded.co.uk/changing-left-to-right.html) which "*does not seem to make much of the forced change in handedness*" is a too sloppy approach on the author's part. It is unfortunate that some people are forced to change handedness (I am left-handed and luckily grew up in a great environment), yet associating *suppressed handedness* with mental disorders seems quite mistaken and thus it misses the true causes of those people's difficulties.

Comment: You may well be right. I just don't want to dismiss the claim without proper investigation.

Comment: @Muze "I want to think" is exactly the wrong attitude here (and in pretty much everything). As soon as you start feeling that you *want* a particular answer, start searching for evidence to the contrary. Only when you don't find it after a diligent search can you start having any confidence that the world really is as you want it to be. Also, try asking over on Skeptics.SE. They specialize in this kind of question.